# Korma: or'ing dynamically generated where clauses

Tags: clojure, korma

I have a set of dynamically generated parameters in a form of a map like

```
(def clauses {:apples 23 :plums 0 :bananas 7})
```

and I want to have it or'ed in a `where` statement, so it should become an equivalent of the Korma query:

```clj
(select fruit-shop
  (where (or {:apples 23}
             {:plums 0}
             {:bananas 7})))
```

Generating a list of maps is quite easy:

```
(map #(apply array-map %)
     (into [] clauses))
```

But one can't use `(or` statement applied to it, because it's handled at macro expansion time, before the `clauses` becomes bound to its value.

What statement should be used in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting familiar with Korma source code, I have found `korma.sql.fns/pred-or` function that replaces `or` statements in `where` and `having`. So I wrote the following helper function that takes a map argument

```
(require '[korma.sql.fns :refer [pred-or]])

(defn or*
  [m]
  (apply pred-or
         (map #(apply array-map %)
              (into [] m))))
```

Given that, the intended query will look like this

```
(select fruit-shop
  (where (or* clauses)))
```